# How I render a blazor component dynamically multiple times instantly in another component (for eg: each button click)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I want to update the view each time when I click the button by dynamically adding other blazor component. How can I achieve this.

For eg: Each time I click the button on component 1, component 2 should be added within the component 1 immediately.

Answer (score 7):

Note: This sample was created long time ago... Currently Blazor supports advanced features that may be utilized for this same purpose.

You can use **Templated components** for this. [Read the linked section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#templated-components), and try to convert my sample to Templated components.

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<li><div>@Title</div></li>  

    @code {
      [Parameter]
      public string Title { get; set; } 
     }
```

### ParentComponent.razor

```
    <p>Type the title for the new component and then click the button<p>

    <input type="text" @bind="@Title" />

   <button @onclick="@AddComponent">New Component</button>

    <div>   
     @if (!list.Any())
        {
            <p>You have no items in your list</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    @item();
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </div>

    @code {

        public List<RenderFragment> list { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
           list = new List<RenderFragment>();
        }


        protected void AddComponent()
        {
                list.Add(CreateDynamicComponent());

        }


        RenderFragment CreateDynamicComponent() => builder =>
        {

            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(ChildComponent));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Title", "Title:  " + Title);
            builder.CloseComponent();

        };
    }
```

Hope this works...